# in array not matching

Tags: templating, array

I am probably doing something daft here, but tried multiple things to no resolution.
I trying to find if a value is in an array but my test case doesn't match.

```
{% if entry.applicationStatus == 'submitted' %}{% endif %}   # matches ok             
{% if entry.applicationStatus in ['submitted'] %}{% endif %} # doesn't match
```

The array check in the above case doesn't match.  entry.applicationStatus is a dropdown menu.
I will want to check for multiple values which is why I want to check if it is in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've bumped into this a few times. It's because `entry.fieldHandleName` when used on a field type with multiple options (dropdowns/radios etc) is in fact a magic shortcut for `entry.fieldHandleName.value`.  You can see this if you `dump` out the variable to the screen: `<pre>{{ dump(entry.applicationStatus) }}</pre>`.

So, you need to append `.value` on to the end: `{% if entry.applicationStatus.value in ['submitted'] %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Ah - makes perfect sense. Thanks!